# Append GridView-Columns after DataTable was databound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataTable`  which I have created in code file and I later bind it to a `GridView` which i have created by using the drag and drop feature of Visual studio.

However I have added some columns in the `GridView` which are not supported(correct me if I am wrong) in a `DataTable`, e.g Hyperlink-Column or CheckBox-Column.

I would like to build the hyperlink column and the checkbox id's with a value derived from a value generated in the `DataTable` from a particular column. I know I can use `DataNavigateUrlfields` to build dynamic links but how do I do this with a `DataTable` that is to be bound later?

I also need the columns in the `GridView` to appear after the columns in the `DataTable`.

Any help in the above will be highly appreciated. Any alternatives are also appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the tag `ASP.NET` is corect since there is no `DataGridview`? Even `DataGrid` is the ancestor of `GridView` in the 1.1 world, so what are you actually using?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry if I was not clear. I am using <asp:Gridview></asp:GridView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaratively added controls will be created first and  then the databound/manually created(documented in the [Page's Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), s‌​earch for *"controls created declaratively"*). Since you want the declarative columns last, you need a hack:

You could use [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) to change the order, so that the `AutoGenerated` columns are followed by your other columns like `Hyperlink` or `CheckBox` columns:

```
protected void gridOffers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
    //Move first to the end
    e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
    cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
    //Move second to the end
    e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

> However I have added some columns in the GridView which are not
>   supported(correct me if I am wrong) in a DataTable, e.g
>   Hyperlink-Column or CheckBox-Column.

They don't need to be supported in the DataTable but in the GridView. The table contains your data and the grid contains the view.

Comment: Thanks but I had to restructure my code to something similar to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn.itemstyle.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - based on `RowDataBound`

```
<Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:HyperLink>
              </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
              </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

You can adjust you datbound with your event RowDataBound, i added HyperLink control, in order to customize your link as you want.

```
 void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      var hyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1");
      hyperLink.NavigateUrl ="...."; 

      var checkBox = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
      checkBox.Checked =....


    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks but I had to restructure my code to something similar to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn.itemstyle.aspx

Comment: I'am happy to help you Max, yes exactly you can also manage your events in child contol (your button) scope, i suggested you to manage yours events in parent control (Grid View with rowcommand event)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an easy way to append a column if you are using datatable

```
DataTable yourDataTable = new DataTable();

Load yourDataTable by DataReader or DataAdapter

DataColumn newColumn = yourDataTable.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(Int32));
```

After that you can bind this datatable into your Gridview.
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd(v=vs.110).aspx)